# Upload JSON file to Google Drive using Google Drive API for android programatically

Tags: android, json, google-drive-android-api

I know from the [sample code](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileActivity.java) how to upload a text file into the Drive AppFolder, but from the docs is not clear how to extend it to JSON, if it's possible at all.

Here is the code for uploading a Text File:

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
            return;
        }
        final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

        // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // write content to DriveContents
                OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                try {
                    writer.write("Hello World!");
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle("New file")
                        .setMimeType("text/plain")
                        .setStarred(true).build();

                // create a file on root folder
                Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                        .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, driveContents)
                        .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
            }
        }.start();
    }
};
```

I need to change the `.setMimeType()` and the `outputStream`, but to what exactly?

my JSON String is declared as follows:

```
String json = gson.toJson(activeSubs); //activeSubs being an ArrayList
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why? Json text is just text. I see no file name in your code.

Comment: that's the sample code from the google samples. So this is the right way to upload a json too? don't need to do anything else?

Comment: I see no file name in your code. And further you can answer your own question by just giving it a try.

Comment: You still did not tell under which file name all would be saved.

Comment: `my JSON file is declared as follows:`. No. That is not a file. It is a String that contains json text.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need right? Then I create a file in the drive appfolder

Comment: `writer.write("Hello World!");` change to `writer.write(json);`

Comment: `.setMimeType("text/json")`

Comment: ok done, add an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

```
String json = gson.tojson(activeSubs);

final private ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
            return;
        }
        final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

        // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // write content to DriveContents
                OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                try {
                    writer.write(json);
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle("New file.txt")
                        .setMimeType("json")
                        .setStarred(true).build();

                // create a file on root folder
                Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                        .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, driveContents)
                        .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
            }
        }.start();
    }
};
```